# Create a SQL Query that compares two tables and return an indicator if value is contained in Table 1 but not in Table2

Tags: sql

I'm working on the below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM eg_table1
LEFT JOIN eg_table2 ON eg_table1.part_id = eg_table2.PRODNO
WHERE eg_table1.part_id LIKE "%ARG1%" AND eg_table2.CCI_PROJECT_ID LIKE '%ARG2%'
```

It works fine, however, when ARG1 is not contained in table2 it doesn't return anything. Could anyone help me find a way to add a functionality to this query to show ARG1 and an indicator that the value is in table 1 but not in table 2?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.Your query is looking for ARG1 in table1. Nowhere are you looking for ARG1 in table 2. You use a LEFT JOIN, which by design returns data residing in the table on the LEFT of the join. The visual indicator is that any columns sourced from table 2 will be NULL values.

Comment: Basically it's going to look for a value in Table 1 where %ARG1% is contained in part_id column, then it's going to look in table2 if this value is found in PRODNO column considering that the %ARG2% also matches in column Project_ID. If found it works and joins as requested, however if this query can't find any match I'd like to receive an indicator that there is a value in table 1 that's not in table 2

Comment: Move eg_table2 conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Please add few rows of sample data and the expected result. It's not 100% clear to me what you want to do.

Comment: Also, your outer join is not working properly. You should place the predicate in the `ON` clause rather than in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @jarlh it worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

When selecting records that are contained in Table1 and not in Table2, this query is usually written that:

```
select * from Table1 t1 
left join Table2 t2 on t2.example_id = t1.example_id 
where t2.id is null
```

**And be careful**: When using left join, so joining conditions should be after the `on` command,  not in the `where` clause.

If you want to show records that contained `ARG1` in Table1 and not contained in Table2, let's change your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eg_table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN eg_table2 t2 ON 
                    t1.part_id = t2.PRODNO and 
                    t2.CCI_PROJECT_ID LIKE '%ARG1%'
WHERE 
    t1.part_id LIKE "%ARG1%" and 
    t2.PRODNO is null
```

How will this query work? I explain:

1. Table1 will be filtered by this condition: `t1.part_id LIKE "%ARG1%"`
2. Table2 will be joined to Table1 by these conditions: `(t1.part_id = t2.PRODNO and t2.CCI_PROJECT_ID LIKE '%ARG1%')`
3. Query will be shown records that `t1.part_id LIKE "%ARG1%" = true` and `(t1.part_id = t2.PRODNO and t2.CCI_PROJECT_ID LIKE '%ARG1%') = false`